# return consecutive duplicated lines in R with count (comparing several columns)

Tags: r, duplicates

I have an input dataframe/datatable looking something like this:

```
ID location jobid
X   city1    1
X   city1    2
Y   city2    3
Y   city3    4
Z   city1    5
X   city1    6
```

And I want to return those lines in which the values ID and location are duplicated in consecutive rows, together with a count (something like uniq -c in bash for selected columns): desired output:

```
ID location count 
X   city1     2
```

Any idea how to do this in R? I treid cumsum, rle but cannot get it right.. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick'n'dirty solution :

```
DF <- 
read.csv(
text="ID,location,jobid
X,city1,1
X,city1,2
Y,city2,3
Y,city3,4
Z,city1,5
X,city1,6",as.is=T)

count <- rle(paste(DF$ID,DF$location,sep='|'))$lengths

res <- cbind(DF[cumsum(count),c('ID','location')],count)

> res
  ID location   count
2  X    city1       2
3  Y    city2       1
4  Y    city3       1
5  Z    city1       1
6  X    city1       1
```

and if you want only those lines having consecutive duplicates, just filter `res` :

```
res[res$count > 1,]

>  ID location   count
2  X    city1       2
```